# (How) does XHTML make a difference?

Tags: xhtml

Why is XHTML needed? How does it stand apart on its own from HTML? When HTML has versions 3, 4, and an expected 5, why xhtml on one hand discontinued with version 2 and suddenly shown as part of HTML5 itself http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-xhtml-syntax.html#the-xhtml-syntax than separate recommendation?

Comment: Hardly "suddenly". XHTML processsing was included as as an integral part of "Web Forms 2.0", one of the forerunners of HTML5 as early as 2004.

Comment: ... and the first published draft of W3C HTML5 in Jan 2008 says: "this specification describes two authoring formats: one based on XML (referred to as XHTML5), and one using a custom format inspired by SGML (referred to as HTML5)."

Comment: good points, thanks for leading me to look into Web Forms 2.0! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XHTML is useful because it can be generated and parsed with standard XML libraries. If you don't need this property, you can use HTML. In HTML 5, it is just an alternative syntax for the same language...

XHTML was not discontinued. XHTML 1.0 (and 1.1) corresponded directly to HTML 4.01. The version of XHTML that corresponds to HTML5 is just called XHTML5 to synchronize the version numbers.
XHTML 2.0 was a discontinued effort at making a completely new document language.

Comment: In other words, how parsing web documents by standard XML libraries add value to web-content? The property is known from the link in question itself, but are there any relevant use-cases today? I am actually searching to justify XHTML5 with sound reasons beyond my preference for XML parsing with my colleagues. Someone might know some as to why the XML serialization content in the HTML5 spec isn't omitted? Why despite discontinuing XHTML2, huge leap from 1.1 to 5 is happening

Comment: The XML syntax is the **ONLY** difference between HTML and XHTML.

1.1 and are **just numbers**. Using 5 as the version number, means the number is in sync with HTML. The HTML version numbers are not consistent either. There is no HTML 1, HTML 2.0 was never really a standard. There was only a version 3.2, never a version 3.0 and so on...
It is a bit like asking why the Windows version name changed from Windows Vista to Windows 7...

Comment: One major reason to use XHTML is if you want to embed an HTML document into another XML document. With XHTML you can use namespaces to distinguish between the XML document and the embedded HTML document. That would not be possible in the HTML syntax.

Comment: By the way, stack overflow is not fit for long discussions an opinions about syntaxes. HTML has two syntaxes: a standard XML syntax (XHTML) and a nonstandard, HTML-specific HTML syntax. This is the only relevant answer in this forum.

Comment: Please give some link outside this forum where this discussion occurred and we may consider to be justified and correctly completed.

Comment: You can just look at the specifications if you are interested in how they relate. It is state up front in both the XHTML and the HTML5 specifications.

Comment: Maybe I just needed help as I lack being well-versed with the spec, or at least its dry theory without rich examples. Still thanks for your time I admitted your answer. & I welcome any links to open examples.